# double pointers to class

Tags: c++, pointers

I remember seeing this line of code on my final exam, still to this day I can't figure it out or a use for it. I tired googling "double pointers" and "Pointer to Array of Classes" and still can't find an answer.

I want to know why you would use something like this (practical use) or direct me to a website that explain this for me. Thank you.

```
vendingMachine **va = new vendingMachine*[numMachines];
```

Comment: Btw, the "homework" tag should not be used anymore in new questions. It's only there for old questions that still have it.

Comment: Try searching for 'pointer to pointer' instead

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't really matter that the type involved is a class. It could just as well be a basic type:

```
int **va = new int*[numInts];
```

The semantics are the same. You have a pointer that points to a pointer. Since dynamically allocated arrays are implemented with pointers, this becomes an array of pointers. Here is a use case:

```
int a, b;
va[0] = &a;
va[1] = &b;
```

But since, as mentioned, you can implement arrays with pointers, you can also treat it as an array of arrays. So you have another use case:

```
va[0] = new int[10];
va[1] = new int[10];
// ...
va[numInts - 1] = new int[10];

va[0][0] = 2;
va[0][1] = 8;
// ...
va[numInts - 1][9] = 3;
```

So you have an array of arrays. Or in other words, a two dimensional array of `int`s. If you now change back from `int` to `vendingMachine`, you'd have a 2D array of `vendingMachine` objects.

Comment: 2D array of vending machines! A very common requirement I find. Good answer BTW.